# Setting the html document width when user is not on mobile device

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I'm making an HTML5 app in jQuery Mobile, and I have this setting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

However, I want the page to display similarly on my PC, as on the smartphone I'm testing on. (Much narrower in other words)

So the question is: How can I set the width of the html document to lets say '760px', when the user is not on a mobile unit? Can I do it in just CSS or do you need JS too? Or can it all be done via a meta tag?

I have tried the following but it doesn't do anything:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    html { width: 760px !important; }
}
```

When inspecting in chrome, the html tag is in fact set to 760px, but the width is still 100% in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already in Chrome, press 'F12' to open the "Developer Tools" and click on the phone icon.  You can then adjust the page to fit your testing needs.

Comment: nice, didnt know about that. however this was very buggy :S